# How do I add more info in cyclical queue implementation with single dimensional table?

Tags: c, data-structures, queue

I am supposed to implement a queue for 25 where each customer receives a number, a time of arrival and a full name. I'd understand how to do it if I could use a list but I'm supposed to use a one dimensional array for a cyclical queue for the implementation. My question is, how am I supposed to save multiple information in each customer ? Do I still need to create a seperate list ?

Comment: I forgot to mention the program is in c.

Answer (score 0):

> how am I supposed to save multiple information in each customer ?

I think you want to create a blueprint/[class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) for a customer to store all the related information.

```
class Customer {
    private String name;
    private int number;
    ...
    // setters, getters to store and retrieve information.
}
```

> Do I still need to create a seperate list ?

No, you don't need to create a seperate list, you can create a list of `Customer`'s like this

```
List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();
```

you might want to look at this for more info on [CircularQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/wls/WLAPI/weblogic/utils/collections/CircularQueue.html)

Comment: Okay thanks but I forgot to mention the program is in c. I have to do the job with functions, no classes involved

Answer (score 0):

> how am I supposed to save multiple information in each customer ?

You should use `struct`. Take a look at this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_structures.htm) to understand Structures in C. Your struct can look something like this :

```
//each customer receives a number, a time of arrival and a full name.
struct customer {
   int num;
   int time;
   char name[100];
};
```

> Do I still need to create a separate list?

No, you don't need a separate list for each of them. Once you have a `struct` defined, you should create a list of these structs.

```
struct customer customer_queue[25];
```